# how to get date time object value in parse cloud using php

Tags: php, parse-platform

i am not get date from UpdatedAt so please help me any suggation.
   please send the code or discus me.
   parse.com not example of DateTime Object

```
 Array
    (
        [objectId] => G1qiPD7W9P
        [UpdatedAt] => DateTime Object
            (
                [date] => 2015-08-24 10:00:06
                [timezone_type] => 2
                [timezone] => Z
            )

        [CreatedAt] => DateTime Object
            (
                [date] => 2015-08-24 10:00:06
                [timezone_type] => 2
                [timezone] => Z
            )

        [bathFullAddress] => Thailand,null,null,Thailand,null
        [bathLocation] => Parse\ParseGeoPoint Object
            (
                [latitude:Parse\ParseGeoPoint:private] => 13.162189296228
                [longitude:Parse\ParseGeoPoint:private] => 100.15680084005
            )

        [bathLocationName] => bangkok
        [bathRating] => 2
        [bathRoomType] => Squat
        [description] => here.
        [userId] => ND36ZxnYrL
    )
```

It is a my code it is using parse api other problem is not get latitute and langtute .

```
  <?php $query = new ParseQuery("BathRoomDetail");
 //$query->equalTo("email", "email@me.com");
 $results = $query->find();
 //echo "Successfully retrieved " . count($results) . " scores.";
 for ($i = 0; $i < count($results); $i++) 
 {    

    $detail=array();
    $object = $results[$i];
    //echo "<pre>";
    //print_r($object);
    $detail['objectId'] = $object->getObjectId();
    $detail['bathRoomType'] = $object->get('bathRoomType');
    $detail['bathFullAddress'] = $object->get('bathFullAddress');
    $detail['UpdatedAt'] = $object->getUpdatedAt();
    //$detail['emailVerified'] = $object->get('emailVerified');
    $response[]=$detail;

 }
```

Comment: echo $yourArray['bathLocation']->toJSON();

Comment: https://parse.com/docs/js/api/symbols/Parse.GeoPoint.html#toJSON

Comment: i am using php not javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to only get the date.

```
$newArr = $varArray['UpdatedAt']->date;
echo $newArr;
```

OR if it is an array. Use `foreach`

```
$updatedAt = [];

$foreach($varComingfrom as $key => $val){
  $updatedAt[] = $val['UpdatedAt']->date;
}

print_r($updatedAt);
```

Comment: please send me other example it is not get a value